# How do I make Alt+Tab switcher to show small windows instead of icons?

Tags: unity

I want to have something like this:
[image]

instead of what I have now:
[image]

UPD:
There is appropriate option in compiz-config, but it doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: Gnome flashback is nice and by default support all shortcut switcher. Read here : https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback